# Windows 10 Start Menu Search Bar Not Showing Installed Programs

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, cortana

I have been having a problem with my start menu in Windows 10!

When I search up a program like "Paint" or "Photoshop" it does not show up! However, built-in apps such as "Settings" and "Edge" show up!

I have tried rebuilding the search index earlier today, but it did not work, so, I am rebuilding the search index again and I am leaving it on overnight!

By the way, the items in my search index is over one million items when it is completed!

What should I do to fix my start menu search bar?

Comment: Do see that programs shortcuts in normal start menu?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [Start Menu troubleshooter](https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/startmenu.diagcab) that is worth trying.

Also you can check if any Windows files are corrupted by running sfc /scannow in the PowerShell.

If nothing helps you can also try to create a new user and see if the same issue happens there as well. If not, you might just want to change to that user and bring over your files and settings.